# Infinite loop on my unit test is confusing me

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, console-application

I am trying to assert the optInput values in my below test which is logically using user input on the console to validate a condition.  But on my second test, for some reason I keep getting an infinite loop as my test result (system.outOfMemoryException).  I have similar tests which are working fine when performing this type of validation but I cannot figure out why the below test won't just assert.fail that when I enter an invalid condition into my parameters, that I get the error response of "Invalid input please try again".  It for some reason continues the function and tries to ask the user for another input.

I tried to refactor my code to match other method logic which also uses user input to validate a condition, and those methods are using IF statements, but that also didn't work.  I'm wondering why this test which loops when an incorrect parameter is passed fails, but other loop methods pass and do not infinite loop in my tests when I assert.fail that a condition should not be met.

```
public string UserAnswer(string optInput = null)
{
    bool isOperatorValid;
    do
    {
        isOperatorValid = true;
        string answer = optInput ?? Console.ReadLine();
        switch (answer)
        {
            case "a":
                Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} + {num2} = " + (num1 + num2));
                break;
            case "s":
                Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} - {num2} = " + (num1 - num2));
                break;
            case "m":
                Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} * {num2} = " + (num1 * num2));
                break;
            case "d":
                Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} / {num2} = " + (num1 / num2));
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input please try again");
                isOperatorValid = false;
                break;
        }
    } while (!isOperatorValid);
    return optInput;
}



[Test]
public void UserAnswer()
{
    var calc = new CalculatorApp.Program();
    var output = new StringWriter();
    string expectedresult = (string.Format("Your result: 0 + 0 = 0\r\n", Environment.NewLine));
    Console.SetOut(output);
    var input = new StringReader("a");
    Console.SetIn(input);

    calc.UserAnswer();

    Assert.That(output.ToString(), Is.EqualTo(expectedresult));
    Assert.False(calc.UserAnswer("t").Equals("Invalid input please try again\r\n"));
    Assert.That(calc.UserAnswer("a").Equals("a"));

}
```

Comment: On invalid input your method waits for new (valid) user input, which your test never provides - that's what your `do` `while` loop is for, after all

Comment: Off-topic, but unit tests should run autonomously - The fact that you are testing something requiring Console.ReadLine() is a red-flag. You should dependency inject a wrapper around Console.ReadLine(), and mock it for your tests.

Comment: true - sorry I should probably research more and then come up with a more solidified question.

I'm very new to unit testing and haven't really touched DI yet - though it a topic which I've watched videos on.  I just want to get it working as easily as I can before I move on to better practices.

Comment: @testingTester You need to remove `string answer = optInput ?? Console.ReadLine();` from the `UserAnswer` method and have that happen upstream in the calling method that isn't part of the method being unit tested.

Comment: @testingTester Also, you shouldn't couple `Console.WriteLine` statements in the same method. Have `UserAnswer` only result in a string and return to another method that will write the result via `Console.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 2):

If `optInput` is non-null but isn't one of "a", "s", "m" or "d", you'll just keep looping round and trying it again - it won't ask for more input (which it can't really, given that it's a unit test).

Fundamentally I think it would be worth trying to abstract the interaction part to something more amenable to unit testing - something where you can write tests for 'What happens if the user first inputs "x" and then "m"?'